# Is there a way to add a different number of columns in each row of a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to add a different number of columns in each row of a CSV file using python.

For example:

[image: screenshot of Excel spreadsheet with different number of rows in its columns]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How exactly are you trying? Please add your code and explain what does not work.

Comment: Yes, in a sense, by putting in empty column values where there aren't values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This illustrates what I meant in my comment about supplying empty values for missing columns. It uses a [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to write the rows.

```
import csv

filename = 'varying_rows.csv'

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['name', 'gender', 'age', 'website1', 'link1'])
    writer.writerow([None]*3 + ['website2', 'link2'])
    writer.writerow([None]*4 +  ['link3'])
```

Resulting file:

[image: screenshot of resulting file in Excel]

You could also get the same result by using a [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) instead which would allow just leaving out the empty columns:

```
filename = 'varying_rows2.csv'
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as file:
    col_names = 'ABCDE'  # Works like ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'].
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, col_names)
    writer.writerow(dict(A='name', B='gender', C='age', D='website1', E='link1'))
    writer.writerow(dict(D='website2', E='link2'))
    writer.writerow(dict(E='link3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so, you can directly write them into the csv.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], ['', 2, 3]
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    for line in a:
        output = ','.join(line)
        f.write( output )
```

Hope this helps.